# Windows $env:path ="$($env:path);." where was it added?

Tags: powershell, path, environment

I "fixed" a problem by running `$env:path ="$($env:path);."` from PowerShell. Apparently it added the current directory to my path. Which path variable did it add to please? In my environment variables dialogue, where would I see it added? User variables? System variables?

I'm confused because I had already added the folder to system variables `path`, but couldn't run the contained script until running ``$env:path ="$($env:path);."

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer or providing feedback, if your question isn't fully answered yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Updates to `$env:EnvVarName` affect the *current process only*** - no persistent changes via the registry are made:

```sh
$env:EnvVarName = 'foo'
```

is the equivalent of calling .NET method [`System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) as follows:

```sh
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('EnvVarName', 'foo', 'Process')
```

That is, the scope of the update is the *current process*.

**Only if you substitute `'User'` or `'Machine'` for `'Process'` in the above call (supported on Windows only<sup>[1]</sup>) do you *persistently* update environment variables in the registry** (for the current user or the local machine (*all* users), respectively), **for *future* sessions (processes)<sup>[2]</sup>.**

<sup>As of PowerShell [Core] 7.2, there is no *PowerShell-native* way to persistently update environment variables, but introducing one is [being discussed on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/92#issuecomment-512603724).</sup>

In other words: **if you want to update not only the registry-based definition but also the value in the current process, you need to make *both* calls**; e.g., for the current user:

```sh
# Windows only: Update / create a persistent definition for the current user,
#               stored in the registry.
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('EnvVarName', 'foo', 'User')

# Update value for current process too.
$env:EnvVarName = 'foo'
```

Or, more in the spirit of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```sh
'User', 'Process' | foreach {
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('EnvVarName', 'foo', $_)
}
```

If the new value is to be based on the existing one from a given registry scope, retrieve the scope-specific value via [`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable); e.g.:

```sh
# Get the registry-based *user* value 
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')
```

---

##### Caveat: Non-support for Windows environment variables based on  `REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry values:

On Windows, persistently defined environment variables may be defined based on *other* environment variables, namely if the underlying registry value defining the variable is of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.

As of .NET 6, the [`System.Environment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment) type's methods do *not* (directly) support such environment variables:

- On *getting* such a variable's value, its *expanded* form is invariably returned; that is, references to other environment variables such as `%SystemRoot%` are replaced by their values.
- On *setting* environment variables, `REG_SZ` registry values are *invariably* created, i.e.   static, verbatim values - even when updating an existing `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value.

While quietly converting `REG_EXPAND_SZ` environment variables to static `REG_SZ` ones may often have no ill effects (as long as the new value only contains literal values), it certainly *can*: for instance, say a variable is defined in terms of `%JAVADIR%`; if that variable is converted to a static value based on the then-current value of `%JAVADIR%`, it will stop working if the value of `%JAVADIR%` is later changed.

Unfortunately, **retrieval of raw `REG_EXPAND_SZ` environment variables and proper updating of their values currently requires *direct registry access***, which is quite cumbersome (not even the Windows API seems to have support for it) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375).

---

##### Important considerations for the `Path` environment variable (`$env:PATH`) on Windows:

- The `Path` environment variable is special in that it is a *composite* value: when a process starts, the in-process value is the *concatenation* of the `Machine` (local machine, for all users) value and the `User` (current user) value.

  - Note that since the machine-level value comes first, its entries take precedence over the user-level value's entries.
- Therefore, if you want to modify (append to) the existing `Path`, it's better *not* to define the new value simply by appending to the existing in-process value (`$env:Path`), because you'll be *duplicating* the `Machine` or `User` values, depending on which scope you target.

  - Instead, retrieve the existing value from the target scope selectively, modify that value (typically by appending a directory, and then write the modified value back to the same scope.
  - To robustly make the same modification effective in the *current process too* is nontrivial, given that the in-process copy of `$env:Path` may have been modified; however, in the simple case of appending a new directory to the user's path, you can simply do `$env:Path += ';' + $newDir`; you may get away with this simple approach in other cases too, but note that the behavior may be different, given that the *order* in which the directories are listed in `$env:Path` matters.

**Important**: The `Path` environment variable on Windows is `REG_EXPAND_SZ`-based by default, so the caveats re the quiet conversion to a static `REG_SZ`-based value that the code below below performs apply - again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375) for a proper, but much more complex solution.

Example:

```sh
# New dir. to add to the *user's* path
$newDir = 'c:\foo\bin'

# Get current value *from the registry*
$userPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')

# Append the new dir and save back to the registry.
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', ($userPath + ';' + $newDir), 'User')

# To also update the current process, append $newDir to the in-process
# variable, $env:Path
$env:Path += ';' + $newDir
```

As an aside: On *Unix-like platforms*, the separator is `:`, not `;` (reflected in `[System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator` , and the *case-sensitive* variable name is `Path`. As stated, .NET fundamentally doesn't offer *persistent* environment-variable definitions on Unix-like platforms (as of .NET Core 3.1), because the various platforms have no unified native mechanism for doing so.

---

<sup>[1] On Unix-like platforms, targeting `User` or `Machine` is *quietly ignored* as of .NET Core 3.1</sup>

<sup>[2] **Caveat**: New processes created directly by the current PowerShell session (direct invocation, `Start-Process`, `Start-Job`) do *not* yet see the registry changes, because the inherit the *current* session's environment.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you take apart that command, you are assigning a new string to the $env:Path variable.  The string is:

```
"$($env.Path);."
```

When you place a $ followed by a set of parens () within a double-quoted string, it causes PowerShell to evaluate the contents of the parens and put the output of that evaluation into the string.  See the help for **about_Quoting_Rules** in PowerShell help, or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7) in the section about evaluating expressions. Therefore:

```
PS C:> $A = "abc"
PS C:> $B = "AB$($A)CD"
PS C:> $B
ABabcCD
```

So the command you posted is appending ";." to the end of your path.  When doing this, the "." will automatically be expanded out to the current directory, so effectively you will be adding a semi-colon plus the current directory to your $env:PATH variable each time you run it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It added to `$env:PATH` at the process scope, meaning it's not set as a user variable or machine variable and the new value does not exist outside of your current PowerShell session. You will not see an environment variable set in this way from the Environment Variables dialog under System Properties.

If you do want to set a persistent environment variable at the `User` or `Machine` scope from PowerShell, you can, but you have to call a special method for this from the `Environment` class, [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8):

```
# Set system (machine) level environment variable
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( 'VARIABLE_NAME', 'VARIABLE_VALUE', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine )

# Set user level environment variable
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( 'VARIABLE_NAME', 'VARIABLE_VALUE', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User )
```

You can also use this method to set a `Process` level environment variable, but you can already do this with the `$env:VARIABLE_NAME = 'VARIABLE_VALUE'` syntax which is idiomatic to PowerShell.

---

> I'm confused because I had already added the folder to system variables `path`

What probably happened here is that you opened a PowerShell session, then went to the `Environment Variables` dialog, and set the variable value. Problem is, normally environment variables, including `PATH`, are only read when the process starts. Most of the time, you just need to restart your PowerShell session to get the new values.

If you have Chocolatey installed, you can use the `refreshenv` command, which reads the current stored environment variables from the registry, and re-sets the variables in the current process. If you want to implement this sort of thing yourself, [here is the source for it](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/b6495f72d1f2b9901747d857467c4ed3f7306391/src/chocolatey.resources/redirects/RefreshEnv.cmd). Though it's written as a `cmd` script, you can reimplement the logic in PowerShell yourself, or just copy the script source yourself to use.

---

Also, don't add `.` to your path. While convenient, it circumvents built in PowerShell security measures. Add the directory with your programs/scripts you want to run by command to your PATH directly, or invoke them from the current directory by prepending the command with `.\`. For example:

```
.\My-ScriptInThisDirectory.ps1
```