# Can't run the command in Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have downloaded **exercism CLI** and added it to the PATH. I can access it using the `exercism` command through cmd but on Windows Powershell, It is giving me the error that It doesn't recognize the command.

Does Powershell uses some different environment variable or am I missing something.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the error in Powershell]

[image: The same command in cmd]

[image: Here's a screenshot of my PATH]

Comment: powershell uses `$` instead of `%%` for variables so obviously `%EXERCISM%` won't work

Comment: PLEASE do not post pics of code/data/errors. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Its a third party application that you have installed and it created all the path and everything so that you can run the commands in cmd prompt. However, there is no package or module for the same in PS. PS has altogether different engine. If you want to run the cmd command in PS, then just simply invoke the command by typing cmd.exe followed by the full path of the exercism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generally speaking**:

- **PowerShell respects the entries in the `Path` environment variable the same way that `cmd` does**.

  - These shells only differ with respect to executing executables located in the *current* directory (assuming it isn't listed in `Path`): `cmd.exe` allows  execution by *name only* (e.g., `exercism`), whereas PowerShell, as a security feature, requires use of a *path* to explicitly signal the intent (e.g., `.\exercism`)
  - After having modified the persistent `Path` definitions in the registry, a *new* shell session has to be started via the Windows GUI shell (Start Menu, taskbar) to see the changes. When in doubt, log off and back on again, or reboot.

**Your `Path` value is misconfigured**:

**There should be *no* references to environment variables such as `%EXERCISM%` in your *in-session* `Path` value** - neither `cmd.exe` nor PowerShell will recognize such references in this context; they interpret the entries *verbatim* (in contexts where variable references *are* recognized, only `cmd.exe` would recognize the syntax form `%EXERCISM%`; the PowerShell equivalent would be `$env:EXERCISM`)

***In the registry***, where the persistent environment-variable definitions are stored, **you *can* base `Path` entries on references to other environment variables** (e.g, `%SystemRoot%\System32`). The system itself ensures that **(shell) processes see only the *expanded* forms of these variables**. That is, **what a process sees as the `Path` variable value is normally a `;` separated list of *verbatim* paths** (and is a concatenation of the machine-level and the user-level values).

This mechanism relies on the **relevant registry `Path` values** - in keys `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` (machine-level) and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` (user-level) - to be **defined as `REG_EXPAND_SZ`**, which they are by default.

Your screenshot suggests that (at least) **your user-level key has been converted to a *static* string value, `REG_SZ`, which *prevents* the necessary expansion of environment-variable references**.

- This quiet corruption can easily happen if you use tools such as `setx.exe` or even the .NET `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` API to update the persistent `Path` values - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60324498/45375).
- The proper way to update the persistent `Path` values is via *direct registry access* (which is unfortunate, given the complexity) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375).

**Fix**:

**Re-convert your persistent user-level `Path` definition to value type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`**, as follows (works analogously for the machine-level definition, in which case elevation (run as admin) is required):

```
$regPath = 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment'
Set-ItemProperty -Type ExpandString -LiteralPath $regPath Path (Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath $regPath Path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something looks broken by something installed.  These reg entries should be reg_expand_sz.  You should not see %VARS% when viewing the path from the commandline.

```
get-item hkcu:\environment | % GetValueKind path
ExpandString

get-item HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session` Manager\Environment | 
  % GetValueKind path
ExpandString
```