# Preserve environment variables using Start-Process

Tags: powershell, anaconda, conda, powershell-core, start-process

I'll start with saying that am new to Powershell.
I'm currently trying to figure out how to set an environment variable in Windows 11 using the Start-Process cmdlet.
I've already tried both with admin privileges and without.
This is what I'm using:

`` Start-Process -FilePath "pwsh" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-Command `"& {`"`$env:WATCHDOG_PROCID = (Start-Process C:\Users\acqui\anaconda3\envs\prog\pythonw.exe {C:\Users\acqui\Documents\Programming\Projects\Watchdog\main.py $mode} -PassThru).Id`"; pause}`"" ``

The variable, though, is neither created, if not already present, nor modified (checking by calling Get-ChildItem Env: from the pwsh that called the subprocess).
The purpose in having WATCHDOG_PROCID is to be able to kill that precise process later on.

Comment: [Powershell Add System Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730544/powershell-add-system-variable)? You might have to restart your session for this. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***process-specific* environment variable you create** is **only visible to the `pwsh` process created by the outer [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call, not also to the *calling process***.

However, in your call the `pwsh` process automatically terminates after defining the environment variable, so the definition is lost.

One option is to keep the `pwsh` session *alive* and continue working *there*, which you can do by placing the `-NoExit` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) parameter before `-Command`.

If instead you want to define the environment variable in the *calling* process, make the `pwsh` call output the desired *value* (remove `` `$env:WATCHDOG_PROCID = ``  from your command), capture it, and set it in the calling process.

---

Note: **There is *no* way to make *all* processes in the user's *current* OS session see a newly defined environment variable**:

When you define an environment variable *persistently* - via [`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60324498/45375):

- *Running* processes typically do *not* pick up this change.

  - Only if running processes are specifically designed to listen to environment changes, and act on them by reloading the redefined environment variable(s), do they see the change(s) right away.
- Processes created *later* in the same OS session *may* see the changes, but that depends on how they are launched.

  - For instance, processes launched later from a preexisting PowerShell session would *not* see the changes, because they inherit the PowerShell session's environment, and PowerShell itself is *not* designed to pick up persistent environment changes dynamically.

In short:

- Given that you're trying to define a value that by definition only has meaning in the *current* OS session - the ID of a launched process - using a *persistent* environment variable is not the right storage mechanism, and a *process-scoped* environment variable must be set on a *per-process* basis.
- You could still use a *persistent* environment-variable definition, IF the other processes that need to know about the variable *explicitly look up the definition in the registry*.

  - Alternatively, you could designate a *file* to store the value in, or use a *custom* registry location.
  - Either way, the information will be stale when the current OS session ends, so you may need extra work to determine whether the currently persisted value is relevant to the current OS session or not (such as comparing the timestamp of when the persistent value was written to the timestamp of when the current OS session was started).

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 for the meticulous response!